# After six documents with Mongoose, I get "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, post, mongoose

I have a button that sends a POST request when clicked on.

```
var time = '00 : 15 . 13' // Example time format

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/time',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { time: time }
})
```

This is the handler for the POST request:

```
router.post('/time', function(req, res) {
  var timeEntry = new Time({ 
    time: req.body.time,
    date: Date.now()
  })
  console.log(timeEntry)
})
```

And here is the Time schema:

```
var TimeSchema = new Schema({
  time: String,
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

var Time = mongoose.model('Time', TimeSchema)

module.exports = Time
```

The `console.log(timeEntry)` works well six times. Once I press the button for the seventh time, nothing happens for a long while. After about a minute or two, I get a message in the JS console that looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/time net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

and then the `console.log()` works. However, it also seems to `console.log()` all the previous times as well. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the repose after handling the post request /time. So logical your  post request is not completed yet.
Try to return status(success or error code after making the entry into db.)
Eg: res.end('It worked!');

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know why I assumed that the request would finish after the function reached the end.